# Rails 4 not firing AJAX callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

```
# coffeescript
$ ->
  $('#new_comment').on 'ajax:success', (event, html) ->
    $('#comments').append(html)

# comments_controller.rb
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(@captcha.values)

  if @captcha.valid? && @comment.save
    render @comment, layout: false
  else
    render partial: 'form', layout: false, status: 400
  end
end

# _comment.html.haml
%h3= @comment.name
%p= @comment.text
```

In the Network inspector (Chrome) I see that the call is sent to the server and the response is being correctly sent back, but for some reason the javascript events are never fired. The coffeescript file is being included in `application.js`, and I have verified that it's being loaded correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is rails using jquery to send the ajax requests? If not, that would explain why the jquery global ajax events aren't being triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers, but I'm afraid my stupidity was the reason for this problem. Because I loaded the form through AJAX, and the handler binding took place when loading the main page, there was no `#new_comment` form to bind the handler to.

By simply adding the coffeescript to the AJAX form everything was solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach the `ajax:success` event to the `document` through to `#new_comment` in your `coffeescript`:

```
$ ->
  $(document).on('ajax:success', '#new_comment', (event, html) ->
    $('#comments').append(html)
```